# Displaying a popup with a fixed message for URLs with target="_blank"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, external

We already have a CSS that adds a "new window" icon, indicating that the link will open a new window:

```css
a[target $="_blank"] {
   padding-right: 15px;
   background: transparent url(http://opi.mt.gov/Images/SiteWide/Icon_External_Link.png) no-repeat center right;
}
```

Our lawyers want a popup message that states some legal mumbo-jumbo for every external link. Unfortunately, we have an extensive web site with possibly 10,000 external links!  It will be prohibitive to find and touch each link to add a class tag, etc.

Is there any way to modify the above code so that the message appears on hover, much like an 'Alt' or 'title' type?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know how to parse/understand your title. Can you paraphrase that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you could add a global function to attach a click event to all your external links based on the proper selector.

for example:

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();    
    var yesno = confirm("Legal!  Sure you want to go to an external source?");
    if (yesno) window.open($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

I'm sure you could do the same with some type of hover message.  Just depends on how you would want to render that.  I just used an confirm dialog in my example.

Comment: **+1** for simple answer, although it's only for preference, I'd use `$(document).on('click', 'a[target="_blank"]', function()` to future proof any `$.ajax()`/Dymanically loaded content.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `:after` css statement, see http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JavaScript too, depending on what kind of action you want to do, if you are running on a touch device, you might want to to a confirm dialog. JSFiddle for [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D6aGb/).

```
var myLinks = document.querySelectorAll('a[target $="_blank"]');
for (var i = 0, length = myLinks.length; i < length; i++) {
    // You can listen for whatever you want, different for touch
    // so you might want to do it on click and do a confirm dialog
    myLinks[i].addEventListener('mouseover', handleLegal, false);
}
function handleLegal (e) {
    // Do what you want here.
    alert('Hi');
}
```